# Simplifying this sigma notation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Is there any way I can simplify this sigma notation?

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^m(5^k)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression and  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: This is simply a geometric sum: $$\sum_{k=1}^m x^k = x\cdot \frac{1-x^{m}}{1-x}$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Let $S = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{m} 5^{k}$ be the sum you're trying to simplify, then you'll have
$$5S=\color{red}{5^2+5^3+\cdots+5^m}+5^{m+1}$$
$$S=5^1+\color{red}{5^2+\cdots+5^{m-1}+5^m}$$
Then, substracting $S$ from $5S$ gives you
$$4S=5^{m+1}-5^1\iff S=\frac{5^{m+1}-5}{4}.$$

In general, for $a\not =1$, you'll get the following using the above method :
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}a^k=\frac{a^{m+1}-a}{a-1}.$$
Note that if $a=1$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{m}1^k=m$ trivially.

Comment: @Ogen: I hope this helps:)

Comment: @EvanW: Thanks:) better now.

Comment: @mathlove I believe your last statement is incorrect; if $a = 1$, then $a - 1 = 0$, so the sum would be $\infty$; this is because $aS - S = (a - 1)S = 0\times S = 0$, so then you cannot actually solve for $S$.

Comment: @feralin: I edited it. That's what I meant.

Comment: @mathlove Ah, sorry. I misunderstood your point.

Comment: @feralin: No worry, better now:)

Comment: @mathlove This was an ingenious solution. I would have never thought of multiplying S by 5 in order to get the closed equation. Thanks a lot. :D

Comment: @Ogen: You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Using the formula $$\sum_{k=0}^{N} x^k=\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}$$ we have:

$$\sum_{k=1}^m 5^k=\sum_{k=1}^m 5^k+5^0-5^0=\sum_{k=0}^m 5^k-1=\frac{5^{m+1}-1}{5-1}-1=\frac{5^{m+1}-1}{4}-1=\frac{5^{m+1}-1-4}{4}=\frac{5^{m+1}-5}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$5+5^2+5^3+...+5^m=5\large\frac{(5^m-1)}{(5-1)}$

It is a GP with first term=$5$ and common ration=$5$